# complex integral and singularity

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, singularity, cauchy-principal-value

How can I solve this problem:

I = $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(t)}{t}\;e^{ipt}\;dt$

where p is real and I know the result of this integral is

I = 0, $|p| > 1$

I = $\pi$, $|p| < 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}dx =\pi,$$ 
it is easy for you to solve this integral.

We see that
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin t}{t}e^{ipt}\,dt&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin t}{t}(\cos pt+i\sin pt)\,dt\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin t\cos pt}{t}\,dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left\{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (1+p)t}{t}\,dt+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (1-p)t}{t}\,dt\right\}.
\end{align}
Now we recall that 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \alpha t}{t}\,dt=
\begin{cases}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt=\pi  , & \alpha >0 \\
-\pi  , & \alpha <0
.\end{cases}
$$

Then we can see that 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin t}{t}e^{ipt}\,dt=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}(\pi+\pi)=\pi , & -1<p<1 \\
0  , & |p|>1
.\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Rewrite
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin t}{t} = \frac{1}{2}\int^1_{-1} e^{ixt}\ dx
\end{align}
then use Fubini's theorem.

Note: In this method you will need to use the Dirac delta function.